# Вставка и обновление объекта

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Вот у меня есть некоторый набор сущностей, которые связаны между собой навигационными свойствами.

В метод приходит такой объект и я делаю, допустим `await context.AddAsync(group);`.

Подскажите, а это нормально, что он все вложенным объектам такой же статус ставит(они будут добавлены после `await context.SaveChangesAsync()`), независимо от того является их идентификатор дефолтным или нет?

Просто в моем сценарии нужно иногда вставить только объект верхнего уровня, а на то, что "снизу" забить.

Получается, что я должен после вызова `await context.AddAsync` пройтись по вложенным объектам и поменять у них статусы на "немодифицировано" или есть какие-то еще варики?

Если да, то есть какие-то варики сделать это проще? Скажем, что бы не обходить весь граф объектов, а выбрать объекты, которые уже находятся в контексте по условию и тут же пометить их.

Comment: А почему вы избегаете кода в своих вопросах?

Comment: @4per да я подумал, что и на словах все понятно)